# Why am I getting "The resource was not found" when I target turicreate visualization to 'browser'?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, turi-create

First of all, I'm new to turicreate and ubuntu. I'm running turicreate on windows 10 by enabling windows subsystem for Linux. I used ***Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*** to install python, turicreate, and jupyter notebook. I cannot enable the visualization of the data on another tab of my browser. Here is the code.

```
import turicreate
sf = turicreate.SFrame('people-example.csv')
turicreate.visualization.set_target(target='browser')
sf.show()
```

By running this, it gives output that says, "Materializing SFrame" and pops up another tab that goes like this, ***"The resource '/index.html?type=plot&id=e64f3efd-aa42-4a70-bde6-a1541f70b35f' was not found."***

But when I use the default target or ***"turicreate.visualization.set_target(target='auto')"*** it shows the data on jupyter notebook without any delay. So, how can I enable the visualization target to 'browser'? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I got the same problem but it works with target="gui"... For the moment I think it's a bug: https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/3164, there is no issue yet